# C free variables used with strtok

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, strtok, invalid-pointer

I already saw post similar to this one, but I found a little difference that drive me in the wrong way.

I have this code:

```
char * token_one = strtok(my_buffer, " ,.-");
char * token_two = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");

free(token_one);
free(token_two);
```

I saw post where people says a **variable used with strtok should not be freed** but why while executing this code I get this:

`free(token_one)` no errors

`free(token_two)` I get "**invalid pointer**"

Why don't I get error in `free(token_one)`? What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: `strtok`'s return values point to the original string. If `my_buffer` is an allocated object, then it makes sense that this might not fail. However, this is another example of causing undefined behaviour and expecting that you'll always get errors, just like expecting a segfault when accessing memory outside of any objects. The correct way to handle this is to stop trying to `free` the return values, and read the documentation on `strtok`.

Comment: If anything needs to be `free`d it would be `my_buffer` but only if that was dynamically allocated, and only after you finish accessing the tokens. If `token_one` is the same as `my_buffer` then that `free` was valid.

Comment: In general, you cannot `free` the result of `strtok`. You could copy the string returned by `strtok` to a buffer allocated by `malloc` (or the non-standard `strdup` function) for example, and `free` that buffer.

Comment: You need to understand that strtok modifies your original string, It does not allocate new strings.

Comment: The contract with malloc+free does not specify that free will detect errors.  It might, sometimes, but you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look how `strtok()` works, it becomes immediately clear:

1. The first call to `strtok()` returns the given pointer, modifying the string pointed to by it by replacing the next separation character with a NUL byte.
2. Any subsequent call, done with `NULL` as the first argument, operates on the saved pointer from before which points to one after the replaced character.

So the first `free()` call succeeds iff your `my_buffer` came from `malloc()`. The second one fails because, well, why shouldn't it? It doesn't come from `malloc()` et al., so calling `free()` on it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: strtok everytime give me the pointer to the next token and put a termination simbol at the end of the token?

Comment: @user4789408 That's roughly what its definition says, yes.

Comment: @user4789408 Yes, but that piece of memory is not a new chunk of memory but it is part of the initial string. As soon as you free your first pointer, any access via the second will be illegal because the memory area where it points to is not yours any more.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the pointer `my_buffer` points to a dynamically allocated character array.

If the string stored in the array does not start from one of this characters `" ,.-"` then the pointer `token_one` returned from the function `strtok` will have the same value as the pointer `my_buffer`. So it can be used to free the allocated memory.

The pointer `token_two` points to the middle of the string. So its value does not point to the previously allocated memory. So the program after this call

```
free(token_two);
```

has undefined behavior.

This statement

```
free(token_two);
```

would be valid if the pointer `token_two` returned from the call of the function `strtok` was a null-pointer. But in this case no action will be performed by the call of `free`.

Consider two examples.

The first one is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *p1  = malloc( 10 );
    char *p2 = p1;

    free( p2 );

    return 0;
}
```

You can use the pointer `p2` to free the memory the address of which initially was stored in the pointer `p1`.

On the other hand, you may not use the pointer `p2` to free the allocated memory if its value points to inside the allocated memory

This program is invalid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *p1  = malloc( 10 );
    char *p2 = p1 + 5;

    free( p2 );

    return 0;
}
```